# Programmatic system call WDCI Unexpected Behavior (Elevated Permissions)

Tags: c++, process, network-programming, wmic, elevated-privileges

If I wanted to disable a specific NIC on Widows, this is how I'd typically do it:

`wmic.exe path win32_networkadapter where "NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection 2'" call disable`

From an elevated permissions / run as administrator command line prompt... and it works, life is good.

So I compiled this simple C++ CLI app:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

#ifndef popen
FILE *__cdecl popen(const char *_Command, const char *_Mode) { return _popen(_Command, _Mode); }
#endif

#ifndef pclose
int __cdecl pclose(FILE *_Stream) { return _pclose(_Stream); }
#endif

std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    while (!feof(pipe.get())) {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe.get()) != NULL) result += buffer;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << exec("wmic path win32_networkadapter where ""NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection 2'"" call disable");
    return 0;
}
```

Which I execute from the same, elevated permissions command line prompt... but the response I get back is:

```
C:\elevatesdh\Debug>elevatesdh.exe
Invalid Verb.
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change this line

```
std::cout << exec("wmic path win32_networkadapter where ""NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection 2'"" call disable");
```

to

```
std::cout << exec("wmic path win32_networkadapter where \"NetConnectionID = 'Local Area Connection 2'\" call disable");
```

But I could be very wrong...